# Conflicting time-zones being reported at the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, time

I am using Linux Mint, and while inserting times using Org mode in emacs I noticed, the times inserted are in Eastern Standard Time, America. That was confusing since I am based in India.

After digging around on how to get the system time in Linux I got the commands `timedatectl` and `date`, whose output I include below. Notice they are different!

How do I set them right to the time zone in India?

```
/home/gary/Dr/MyWiki ❯ date                                           
Thu 11 May 2023 02:29:30 PM EDT
/home/gary/Dr/MyWiki ❯                                                
/home/gary/Dr/MyWiki ❯ timedatectl                                   
               Local time: Thu 2023-05-11 23:59:36 IST
           Universal time: Thu 2023-05-11 18:29:36 UTC
                 RTC time: Thu 2023-05-11 18:29:36    
                Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)  
System clock synchronized: yes                        
              NTP service: n/a                        
          RTC in local TZ: no                         
/home/gary/Dr/MyWiki ❯
```

Comment: At what time did you run the above commands ?

Comment: just before asking

Comment: Which of the above times was correct ?

Comment: Local time: Thu 2023-05-11 23:59:36 IST

Comment: Are you sure your time-zone is correct ? See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110529/17660).

Comment: What output do you get for `$TZ` and for `date +%z`?

Comment: @YisroelTech For `echo $TZ`   I get `America/New_York` For `date +%z` I get                                                                `-0400`

Comment: Okay, so you know where the `date` utility is taking it's info, the question is where this environment variable is being set. What time zone do you gave in the System Settings (Date & Time option)? Also what do you get for `cat /etc/timezone`, and do you have anything set for **TZ** in `~/.bashrc`?